# How to loop this function in every 30 second?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello building ionic app that get a connecting wifi info and send it to firebase

this function work normally
but I want  1 time button click to loop this function to send value in every 30 second and if button click again will stop loop.

can someone teach me how to do please?

button code

```
<button
    class="button icon-left ion-radio-waves button-positive inactive b_resize"
     ng-click='getWifiInfo();'>Send Wifi info
</button>
```

function code

```
$scope.getWifiInfo = function() { //get wifiinfo
        function success(results) {

                $scope.wifiinfo=results; 
                $scope.$apply();          

              $scope.currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(),'EEEE,d MMMM, y');
              $scope.currentTime = $filter('date')(new Date(),'h:mm:ss a');


              fireBaseData.refUser().child($scope.user_info.uid).child("wifiinfo-record").child($scope.currentDate).child($scope.currentTime).push({  



                                //wifi data send to wifiinfo-record
                                SSID: $scope.wifiinfo.SSID,
                                MacAddress:$scope.wifiinfo.BSSID,
                                SignalStrength: $scope.wifiinfo.Rssi,
                                type:"record",

                              });


                  };
        function err(e) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
              };        
              WifiInfo.getWifiInfo(success,err);
        }
```

Comment: Please maintain standard of Stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `setInterval`

```
function foo(){
    console.log('function is being called')
}

var interval = setInterval(foo, 30000);
```

and to stop it you'll do:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: if OP are really interested to modify scope variables inside that callback, the do prefer to use `$interval` service meant for the same

Comment: I made it!, Thank you for your advice

Comment: @PankajParkar You're right, I didn't even realize it was angular. OP it's the same concept. Look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval